# python/tkinter - image viewer application

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to make simple image viewer, where you can adjust brightness, contrast, color and sharpness with scale. I'm doing it with tkinter and PIL. So far I have two classes, one for brightness and another for sharpness and I just can't find a way(I'm a beginner) to draw two scales in one window and  one picture, which can be modified by this scales. All i could do was to draw scales, two pictures, where each scale modified their own picture.
Sending a code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageEnhance


class Enhance(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image, name, enhancer, lo, hi):
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.mode, image.size)
       self.enhancer = enhancer(image)
       self.update("1.0")
       w = Label(self, image=self.tkim)
       w.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)
       s = Scale(self, label=name, orient=VERTICAL,from_=hi, to=lo, resolution=0.01,command=self.update)
       s.set(self.value)
       s.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 0, pady = 0) 

def update(self, value):
    self.value = eval(value)
    self.tkim.paste(self.enhancer.enhance(self.value))


class Enhance1(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master, image, name, enhancer, lo, hi):
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.mode, image.size)
       self.enhancer = enhancer(image)
       self.update("1.0")
       w = Label(self, image=self.tkim).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)
       s = Scale(self, label=name, orient=VERTICAL,from_=hi, to=lo, resolution=0.01,command=self.update)
       s.set(self.value)
       s.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 0, pady = 0)

def update(self, value):
    self.value = eval(value)
    self.tkim.paste(self.enhancer.enhance(self.value))


root = Tk()

im = Image.open("plant.jpg")   #choose your image

Enhance(root, im, "Brightness", ImageEnhance.Brightness, 0.0, 3.0).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)
Enhance1(root, im, "Sharpness", ImageEnhance.Sharpness, -1.0, 5.0).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to draw one picture and two scales in one tkinter window and be able to modify the picture using them

Answer (score 0):

It's a design problem, not a Python one. You have to decouple the scales (possibly with a "ScaleDrawer" class) and enhancers from your frame and image, and the Frame class should take a list of enhancers and a list of "ScaleDrawer" objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I slightly don't understand, what you wrote. So, should I make two classes, the first "ScaleDrawer" and then the second one Frame or should I make classes even for image and enhancers ?  Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting both of the frames that hold the scales in the same spot -- row 0, column 0. If you want them to appear side-by-side you need to put them in different columns, or use `pack`.

Second, when using grid you should use the sticky argument, so that widgets expand to fill their containers. Also, you need to use the `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` methods to give at least one row and one column a weight of 1 (one) or more, so that your GUI has proper resize behavior. For simple layouts where everything is left-to-right or top-to-bottom, `pack` requires a few less lines of code.

Third, since you want both sliders to affect the same image, you don't want to create a label with the image in each of your classes `Enhance` and `Enhance1`. Instead, create a single image and put it in a single label. So, at the highest level you might create three widgets: a Label, an instance of `Enhance`, and an instance of `Enhance1`.

Finally, you seem to have an indentation error. The method `update` isn't indented, so it's not part of the class definition. Also, since this method is part of a class that subclasses Frame, you shouldn't call this method `update`, because that's a built-in method of all tkinter widgets.

My recommendation is to start over, rather than try to fix what you have. Begin with a blank slate, and first try to get the basic layout working before worrying about the sliders. This lets you focus on one thing instead of trying to get everything working at once.

For example, start with something like this to get the basic structure of your program (notice that I am not doing a global import, and I made the main program a class too, to help cut down on the need for global variables.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ImageViewer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="green")

        # for now, don't use images. This, so that we can get
        # the basic structure working
        self.im = None
        self.tkim = None

        # these three widgets make up our main layout
        label = tk.Label(self, image=self.tkim, text="label")
        e = Enhance(self, self.im)
        e1 = Enhance1(self, self.im)

        # grid works as well as pack in this case, but requires a
        # little more code. For that reason I prefer pack for very
        # simple layouts such as this.
        label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        e.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        e1.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)


class Enhance(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
        # we will be operating on this image, so save a 
        # reference to it
        self.image = image

        # width, height, and color are only temporary, they
        # make it easy to see the frames before they have
        # any content
        self.image = image
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="bisque", width=100, height=100)

class Enhance1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
        # we will be operating on this image, so save a 
        # reference to it
        self.image = image

        # width, height, and color are only temporary, they
        # make it easy to see the frames before they have
        # any content
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="blue", width=100, height=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ImageViewer(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Notice how the areas resize properly as the window is resized. Once we get that working, we can add widgets to the inner frames without having to worry about how they affect the main layout.

With this, you now have a good foundation for building up your GUI. Start by fleshing out just one of the `Enhance` classes, and make sure it's working exactly as you want. Then, do the same for the second one.

Comment: Really thank you ! Appreciate your help, but I have another problem in Enhance class which I can't solve. Should I make new question or post it somewhere here(it's too long for comment).

Comment: @Chilcone: new question.